# How to compare nested quasi poisson models?

Tags: count-data, poisson-regression, quasi-likelihood

I have the following nested quasi poisson models for overdispersed count data:

```
    m1=glm(Total_fulvus_broods~ Temp_offset+ AverageHumidity,family=quasipoisson, data=chamberData)

    m2=glm(Total_fulvus_broods~ Temp_offset,family=quasipoisson, data=chamberData)
```

I want to compare these two models to see if AverageHumidity is a significant predictor. Am I correct in using an F-test (rather than "Chisq"), specified as so:

```
    anova(m2,m1,test="F")
```